# Gradle dependency from own server

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have some projects uses same code, for example my custom logger. I use `Gradle` for assembling my projects. I want to extract this logger as dependency for all project needs it. It is simple to add it as module for project, it is clear.

But I want to put this logger module (as `Gradle module` or `aar`) at my server and use link for it in dependencies for include into my project. There is guide how I can add my own project to maven central, but is it real to have just simple web-server for this purpose.

Comment: Have a look at the gradle documentation, there are several options.

Comment: If I understood well, gradle works only with Maven and Ivy related servers?